# ArrayList with type declaration

Tags: java

I don't know weather its a right place to ask .I have a class name inside array list type declaration. What does it mean ? I might be missing some part of java tutorial .

```
  public ArrayList<Num> arr ;
```

Comment: It's a generic type and means the elements in the list are of type `Num`. The compiler will use that to check whether an operation is allowed or not, i.e. `arr.add(new Num())` would be allowed while `arr.add(new String(""))` would not since `String` doesn't extend `Num`.

Comment: @Thomas I wonder,  I have typed exactly same comment

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera wll, great minds think alike ;)

Comment: You can have a look at generics documentations. It was added for type safety.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html

Comment: @Thomas Perfect I have that operation going in my next lines of codes. Stack overflow my new home ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about Java generics, that's the applicable concept: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

You declared variable that stores ArrayList of

```
Num
```

objects.